# create a PHP/mysql array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

Sorry folks, being thick (please excuse) I have 3 MySql tables with data.  Each table has a "common field" of a date (datestamp) I need to combine the select query from each table and order the array by the "overall" date.  The date stamp field in each table has a different name.
e.g. table1 - date is table1_date etc.

It is not a matter of "joining" the select queries unless it is possible to run the 3 queries as subqueries?

The data fields in each table will differ so what I need to create is a single array ordered with the datestamp fields (desc).  Naturally I can select query for each table.

eg. array1 would be (i think) (I want to use the field name as a key inside the array hence this below)

```
array = table1_date=>array(//field named => field values //)
array2 = table2_date=>array(//field named => field values //)
array3 = table3_date=>array(//field named => field values //)
```

I'm being "thick" because I can create the arrays, I can `array_push` together but can I sort on the datestamp array key - no.

It's prob so easy so I do apologise

Comment: do u want to merge 3 arrays ?

Comment: By common field, do you mean a foreign key? Essentially it is a common value that can reference one table to another.

Comment: Using a timestamp as the primary key is usually a very bad idea - 2 things can happen at the same time. One thing can take more than a second to happen.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say much about the structure of the data in the three tables, but I can't see any reason why you can't do the sorting and fetching in a single query.

Table A
 - datefield
 - fieldA

Table B
 - datefield
 - fieldB

Table C
 - datefield
 - fieldC

now you can fetch the data in a single query in different ways. The simplest would be something like

```
select
  a.datefield datefield,
  a.fieldA datafield
from
  tablea a
union
  select
    b.datefield,
    b.fieldB
  from
    tableb b
union
  select
    c.datefield,
    c.fieldB
  from
    tablec c
order by
  datefield
```

If you only want the sorting, but don't want to union the fields you can do that by eg:

```
select
  a.datefield datefield,
  a.fieldA datafielda
  null datafieldb
  null datafieldc
from
  tablea a
union
  select
    b.datefield,
    null
    b.fieldB
    null
  from
    tableb b
union
  select
    c.datefield,
    null
    null
    c.fieldB
  from
    tablec c
order by
  datefield
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I get your problem quite right but why don't you do something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*,
t2.field1,
t2.field2,
t3.field1,
...
FROM t1
JOIN t2
JOIN t3
ORDER BY t1.dat
```

So that if t1.dat1 = t2.dat2 = t3.dat3, just select one of them in your query (and don't select t2.dat2 nor t3.dat3) and order your query with this one

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the three arrays containing say the rows of your tables, you could merge the arrays (**merge_array()**) and the sort the resulting array with a user defined function (**usort()**)

Here's an example:

```
$array_to_sort = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);

function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($a['datetime']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['datetime']);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}    
usort($array, 'date_compare');
```

**usort()** will then pass to your user defined control two elements of the array, in which you can perform the date check. The check will return the difference, so that the result will be 0 if both dates are equal, a positive number if the first one (**$a**) is larger or a negative value if the second argument (**$b**) is larger. **usort()** uses this information to sort the array.